# How to examine the Optimization of MySQL work or not?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a MySQL table called 'EventTable', to store the information of events, including their types, 
occurring time, and content, etc. I have removed some redundant data from table and used command `optimize table EventTable` to free the unused space and improve the performance, then it shows

```
+----------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------  -------------------------------------------- +
| Table | Op | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+----------+----------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- +
| EventTable | optimize | note | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| EventTable | optimize | status | OK |
+----------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

then according to http://www.justin.my/2010/09/table-does-not-support-optimize-doing-recreate-analyze-instead/

I use

`ALTER TABLE advcms.event ENGINE='InnoDB';`

instead, but the table remains exactly the same, the index doesn't change at all.

Then I found the comment below the article describes that it's not neccessary to use the latter to replace the former, bacause "For InnoDB tables, OPTIMIZE TABLE is mapped to ALTER TABLE".

So, is there any method to examine the "Optimization" work as I expect?

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Answer (score 1):

`OPTIMIZE` and the plain `ALTER` both do the same thing.  And it may be effectively 'nothing'.

There is no way to find out what it did other than `SHOW TABLE STATUS` (or the equivalent query into `information_schema`).

```
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'parts3'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: parts3
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 6726
 Avg_row_length: 31
    Data_length: 212992
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 0
      Data_free: 665845760
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2014-03-05 13:10:04

mysql> OPTIMIZE TABLE parts3;
+-------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table       | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
+-------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test.parts3 | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| test.parts3 | optimize | status   | OK                                                                |
+-------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.52 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'parts3'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: parts3
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 6726
 Avg_row_length: 31
    Data_length: 212992
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 0
      Data_free: 665845760
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2014-03-05 13:10:04
```

Here's another:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'j_1'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: j_1
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 949
 Avg_row_length: 466
    Data_length: 442368
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 294912
      Data_free: 665845760
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2014-03-05 13:10:34

mysql> OPTIMIZE TABLE j_1;
+---------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
+---------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| try.j_1 | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| try.j_1 | optimize | status   | OK                                                                |
+---------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.61 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'j_1'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: j_1
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 980
 Avg_row_length: 351
    Data_length: 344064
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 393216
      Data_free: 665845760
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2014-03-05 13:10:34
```

The first showed no changes; the second showed several changes.  I *believe* that the first did actually rebuild the table and the indexes, but they happened to come out exactly the same size.

Each *secondary* index is a BTree composed of 1 or more 16KB blocks in the "Data_length".

**`OPTIMIZE TABLE` is almost never worth doing on InnoDB tables.**